# Why are my referenced papers not identified by Semantic Scholar and ResearchGate?

Tags: publications

[My paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.13731) lists 83 articles in the reference section. However, [Semantic Scholar only identifies 5 of them](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/VoiceFixer%3A-Toward-General-Speech-Restoration-With-Liu-Kong/8aca925fe0253eb156cee794733386b5e099c362). One of the 5 identified references, Jae S. Lim (1986), does not even appear in my article. [ResearchGate only identifies 4 references.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/354949822) [There is only Prophy that is successfully parsing all my references](https://www.prophy.science/article/146375104-VoiceFixer-Toward-General-Speech-Restoration-with-Neural-Vocoder/).

I'm so confused. I'd appreciate it if someone could help me to get my reference identified by Semantic Scholar and ResearchGate.

Comment: While the question is somewhat different, I think this answer https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/173339/69838 also answers your question.

Comment: As far as I understand it, Researchgate only identifies (and links) references that are also on Researchgate.

Comment: You can report issues to semantic scholar here, under the bibliographic data section: https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.13731

Comment: Well, there is clearly some cutting edge ML at work here.